Postgresql showing only one decimal, Grafana showing 2
I don't understand how this is possible but for some reason, the bid/ask columnsonly show one decimal (should show 2):
arb_finder=# select * from order_book where exchange = 'Coinbase' and currency_1 = 'BTC' and timestamp >= timestamp '2024-07-23 10:36:36' and timestamp < timestamp '2024-07-23 10:36:40';
   id    |         timestamp          | currency_1 | currency_2 |   bid_q   |   bid   |   ask   |   ask_q    | exchange
---------+----------------------------+------------+------------+-----------+---------+---------+------------+----------
 1407052 | 2024-07-23 10:36:36.038745 | BTC        | USD        |  0.102793 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 | 0.00105211 | Coinbase
 1407053 | 2024-07-23 10:36:36.0886   | BTC        | USD        |   0.08678 | 66957.8 | 66960.2 | 0.00105212 | Coinbase
 1407054 | 2024-07-23 10:36:36.138261 | BTC        | USD        |   0.08678 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |  0.0342719 | Coinbase
 1407055 | 2024-07-23 10:36:36.23883  | BTC        | USD        |  0.187353 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |  0.0342719 | Coinbase
 1407056 | 2024-07-23 10:36:36.288232 | BTC        | USD        |  0.406555 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |  0.0343101 | Coinbase
 1407057 | 2024-07-23 10:36:36.343896 | BTC        | USD        |  0.380639 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |  0.0343101 | Coinbase
 1407058 | 2024-07-23 10:36:36.535402 | BTC        | USD        |  0.380639 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |  0.0343118 | Coinbase
 1407059 | 2024-07-23 10:36:36.740284 | BTC        | USD        |  0.161437 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |  0.0353636 | Coinbase
 1407060 | 2024-07-23 10:36:36.972845 | BTC        | USD        |  0.162024 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |  0.0353636 | Coinbase
 1407061 | 2024-07-23 10:36:37.035819 | BTC        | USD        |  0.162024 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |  0.0343118 | Coinbase
 1407062 | 2024-07-23 10:36:37.334264 | BTC        | USD        |  0.370875 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |  0.0240962 | Coinbase
 1407063 | 2024-07-23 10:36:37.432583 | BTC        | USD        |  0.162024 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |  0.0240962 | Coinbase
 1407064 | 2024-07-23 10:36:37.492267 | BTC        | USD        |  0.370595 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |  0.0240962 | Coinbase
 1407065 | 2024-07-23 10:36:37.539213 | BTC        | USD        |  0.370595 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |   0.101096 | Coinbase
 1407066 | 2024-07-23 10:36:37.592276 | BTC        | USD        |  0.162024 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |   0.101096 | Coinbase
 1407067 | 2024-07-23 10:36:37.688685 | BTC        | USD        | 0.0766505 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |   0.101096 | Coinbase
 1407068 | 2024-07-23 10:36:37.790094 | BTC        | USD        | 0.0752607 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |   0.101096 | Coinbase
 1407069 | 2024-07-23 10:36:37.989782 | BTC        | USD        |  0.115134 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |   0.101096 | Coinbase
 1407070 | 2024-07-23 10:36:38.189248 | BTC        | USD        |   0.32433 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |   0.101096 | Coinbase
 1407071 | 2024-07-23 10:36:38.223394 | BTC        | USD        |  0.115134 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |   0.101096 | Coinbase
 1407072 | 2024-07-23 10:36:38.43737  | BTC        | USD        |  0.116524 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |   0.101096 | Coinbase
 1407073 | 2024-07-23 10:36:38.488503 | BTC        | USD        |  0.356598 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |  0.0990962 | Coinbase
 1407074 | 2024-07-23 10:36:38.527654 | BTC        | USD        |  0.336855 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |  0.0990962 | Coinbase
 1407075 | 2024-07-23 10:36:38.677178 | BTC        | USD        |  0.335465 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |  0.0990962 | Coinbase
 1407076 | 2024-07-23 10:36:38.885509 | BTC        | USD        |  0.336855 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |  0.0990962 | Coinbase
 1407077 | 2024-07-23 10:36:39.091913 | BTC        | USD        |  0.127504 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |  0.0990962 | Coinbase
 1407078 | 2024-07-23 10:36:39.238957 | BTC        | USD        |  0.148094 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |  0.0990962 | Coinbase
 1407079 | 2024-07-23 10:36:39.29049  | BTC        | USD        |  0.409813 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |  0.0990962 | Coinbase
 1407080 | 2024-07-23 10:36:39.334706 | BTC        | USD        |  0.201914 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |  0.0990962 | Coinbase
 1407081 | 2024-07-23 10:36:39.386161 | BTC        | USD        |  0.412944 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |  0.0990962 | Coinbase
 1407082 | 2024-07-23 10:36:39.4421   | BTC        | USD        |  0.412944 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |  0.0990962 | Coinbase
 1407083 | 2024-07-23 10:36:39.48631  | BTC        | USD        |   0.25149 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |  0.0990962 | Coinbase
 1407084 | 2024-07-23 10:36:39.541874 | BTC        | USD        |    0.2501 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |  0.0990962 | Coinbase
 1407085 | 2024-07-23 10:36:39.635424 | BTC        | USD        |   0.25149 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |  0.0990962 | Coinbase
 1407086 | 2024-07-23 10:36:39.690689 | BTC        | USD        |    0.2501 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |  0.0990962 | Coinbase
 1407087 | 2024-07-23 10:36:39.838419 | BTC        | USD        | 0.0404599 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |  0.0990962 | Coinbase
 1407088 | 2024-07-23 10:36:39.927487 | BTC        | USD        | 0.0404599 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 |   0.100148 | Coinbase
(37 rows)

I think the data stored is actually with a greater precision as I can see 2 decimals in the data pulled from Grafana:

(Grafana displays in BST, while the raw data is in UTC, hence the 1h difference)
What's even more confusing is that when importing the data in pandas, it also only shows with 1 decimal:
# Define your SQL query
query = """
SELECT 
    timestamp, 
    bid,
    ask
FROM 
    order_book
WHERE 
    exchange = 'Coinbase' AND 
    currency_1 = 'BTC' AND
    timestamp >= timestamp '2024-07-23 10:36:36' AND
    timestamp < timestamp '2024-07-23 10:36:40'
ORDER BY timestamp
"""

df = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine)

print(df)

                    timestamp      bid      ask
0  2024-07-23 10:36:36.038745  66957.8  66957.8
1  2024-07-23 10:36:36.088600  66957.8  66960.2
2  2024-07-23 10:36:36.138261  66957.8  66957.8
3  2024-07-23 10:36:36.238830  66957.8  66957.8
4  2024-07-23 10:36:36.288232  66957.8  66957.8
5  2024-07-23 10:36:36.343896  66957.8  66957.8
6  2024-07-23 10:36:36.535402  66957.8  66957.8
7  2024-07-23 10:36:36.740284  66957.8  66957.8
8  2024-07-23 10:36:36.972845  66957.8  66957.8
9  2024-07-23 10:36:37.035819  66957.8  66957.8
10 2024-07-23 10:36:37.334264  66957.8  66957.8
11 2024-07-23 10:36:37.432583  66957.8  66957.8
12 2024-07-23 10:36:37.492267  66957.8  66957.8
13 2024-07-23 10:36:37.539213  66957.8  66957.8
14 2024-07-23 10:36:37.592276  66957.8  66957.8
15 2024-07-23 10:36:37.688685  66957.8  66957.8
16 2024-07-23 10:36:37.790094  66957.8  66957.8
17 2024-07-23 10:36:37.989782  66957.8  66957.8
18 2024-07-23 10:36:38.189248  66957.8  66957.8
19 2024-07-23 10:36:38.223394  66957.8  66957.8
20 2024-07-23 10:36:38.437370  66957.8  66957.8
21 2024-07-23 10:36:38.488503  66957.8  66957.8
22 2024-07-23 10:36:38.527654  66957.8  66957.8
[...]

What am I missing here?
Here's the structure of the order_book table:
arb_finder=# \d order_book
                                        Table "public.order_book"
   Column   |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                Default
------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------
 id         | bigint                      |           | not null | nextval('order_book_id_seq'::regclass)
 timestamp  | timestamp without time zone |           |          | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 currency_1 | text                        |           | not null |
 currency_2 | text                        |           | not null |
 bid_q      | real                        |           | not null |
 bid        | real                        |           | not null |
 ask        | real                        |           | not null |
 ask_q      | real                        |           | not null |
 exchange   | text                        |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "order_book_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)

Edit:
I've just tried to insert a test entry with 2 decimals to rule out an issue with the actual data inserted and it still displays with only one decimal:
arb_finder=#  insert into order_book (timestamp, currency_1, currency_2, bid_q, bid, ask, ask_q, exchange) values (now(), 'TEST', 'USD', 0.102793, 66957.82, 66957.83, 0.00105211, 'Coinbase');
arb_finder=# select * from  order_book where currency_1 = 'TEST';
   id    |         timestamp          | currency_1 | currency_2 |  bid_q   |   bid   |   ask   |   ask_q    | exchange
---------+----------------------------+------------+------------+----------+---------+---------+------------+----------
 1462509 | 2024-07-23 11:57:19.658942 | TEST       | USD        | 0.102793 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 | 0.00105211 | Coinbase
(1 row)

I then tried with a smaller number and it worked:
arb_finder=#  insert into order_book (timestamp, currency_1, currency_2, bid_q, bid, ask, ask_q, exchange) values (now(), 'TEST', 'USD', 0.102793, 57.82, 66957.83, 0.00105211, 'Coinbase');
INSERT 0 1
arb_finder=# select * from  order_book where currency_1 = 'TEST';                                                                  id    |         timestamp          | currency_1 | currency_2 |  bid_q   |   bid   |   ask   |   ask_q    | exchange
---------+----------------------------+------------+------------+----------+---------+---------+------------+----------
 1462509 | 2024-07-23 11:57:19.658942 | TEST       | USD        | 0.102793 | 66957.8 | 66957.8 | 0.00105211 | Coinbase
 1464557 | 2024-07-23 11:58:11.950465 | TEST       | USD        | 0.102793 |   57.82 | 66957.8 | 0.00105211 | Coinbase
(2 rows)

Is it that I should be using a different data type (eg double precision instead of real)? But if that's the case, how come Grafana seems to be pulling 2 decimal precision?

Bid and Ask are of data type real. The PostgreSQL version is 11.22 (Raspbian 11.22-0+deb10u2). And SHOW extra_float_digits; returns 0. But Bid_q and Ask_q are also real and show 6 decimals.

Please show the DDL of the table order_book

Do you mean this?
arb_finder=# \d order_book

(too long, I'll add to my post)

What's the data type of these columns, what is your PostgreSQL version, and what is your setting for extra_float_digits? And yes, you should add extra information to the question.

Bid and Ask are Real. Pg version is PostgreSQL 11.22 (Raspbian 11.22-0+deb10u2).
And SHOW extra_float_digits; returns 0.
But Bid_q/Ask_q are also reals and show 6 decimals

The answer is in the lacking precision of floating point values.  When you convert numbers between the decimal system and the binary representation used for floating point numbers, the result is usually not exact.  For example, the binary representation of 0.1 has infinitely many decimal places.  PostgreSQL tries to show only as many digits as can be guaranteed to be loss-free during this conversion. One of the reasons for that is that the displayed numbers should stay the same if you pg_dump and restore a database.
For that reason, PostgreSQL has a parameter extra_float_digits that controls how many digits are shown. The default value of 0 guarantees the stability of numbers as described above. Note that the implementation and meaning of this parameter changed in v12, the default value is now 1, but the general idea is the same.
It seems like the Grafana interface is using a higher value for extra_float_digits than the default setting you are using in psql.
Note that the number of digits that are shown is not the same for each number; it depends on the value.
I am not certain why Grafana does what it does, but my guess is that it uses the default setting for extra_float_digits from PostgreSQL v12 on. So perhaps all you have to do to make the difference disappear is to upgrade to a supported PostgreSQL version.

Thanks a lot. Before I saw this, I tried setting extra_float_digits to 3 and when querying the data I'd inserted manually with exactly 2 decimals, I got some fantasist extra decimals (66957.8203 instead of 66957.82, 57.8199997, instead of 57.82), which I suppose lines up with you explained above.
Why do bid/ask_q display with 6 decimals despite also being real? Is it because they are smaller numbers and they can be encoded with greater precision over the 4 bytes a real has?

Additionally, would changing bid and ask to being double precision (which is encoded over 8 bytes) solve my problem?

They can be encoded with greater precision, it seems. You can look at the source; I am to lazy to research this to the end (particularly for a version that is out of support).

double precision has way more significant numbers, but the fundamental problem is the same. If Grafana changes the setting for extra_float_digits, you might see a difference for numbers with many decimal places.

Oh, I require 2 decimals in Grafana. Didn't realize these could actually be incorrect. That's good to note too. Thanks for your help. I'll try changing the type from real to double precision

Changing bid and ask from real to double precision did the trick. Thanks Laurenz!
